# When a Tenured Professor colludes with a friend to harass an undergraduate out of the dept

Tags: ethics

I made a rude comment to my advisor's spouse when I was 19.  I have recently discovered that she and a tenured professor in a program that I declared a second major in were/are good friends, and the two planned and plotted ways to harass me out of that major - in order to avenge the offended spouse.  Is this unethical?  All logic says yes, but I would like to know if it is common. Needless to say, I learned nothing in this major as the environment was hostile to say the least.  But I finished.

Comment: What does this have to do with academia? This could happen in any environment involving humans (maybe even other animals too).

Comment: Of course ethics operate in every walk of life (I believe). And no one is exempt I suppose from violating ethics they don't possess. But, when one has the power to shape the dialogue of current thinking, I should hope one understands the limits of his own mortality.  Sometimes I think tenure has a way of making men into gods.

Comment: Replace "tenure" with "authority" and "men" with "people" then this could be said of any environment.

Comment: I am sorry that many people here seem to be jumping to the conclusion that you are delusional.  However, I don't think your question is a good fit for this site.  As Austin Henley pointed out, it is not specifically about academia.  Also, the obvious answer (yes, it is unethical; no, it is not common) doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor and Austin, for your feedback.  I was under the impression that questions about ethics in academia were ok.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding ethics and/or academia in whatever context is specific to this site. Thank you also to Wofgang and Buzz for your feedback. Everyone have a great night!

Answer (score 5):

If this has happened, of course it is unethical.  Students should be entitled to study in their chosen field, without interference from faculty who may dislike them for purely personal reasons.

However, the scenario you outline actually sound pretty far-fetched.  It may have happened as you say, but I suspect that, whatever personal animosity there may be between you and these faculty members, there may have also been a significant misunderstanding on your part of what has actually transpired.

Comment: Yes, I know it does sound far-fetched. There is quite a back-story, however.  It took me years to come to terms with the kind of abuse that I experienced as an undergraduate. Nothing sexual or even directly verbal, but trust me when I tell you that fiction does less to entertain.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever someone states that the "others" have conspired against "you", my general assumption is that the problem is with "you", not "them". That may or may not be true in your case, but it would probably behoove you to critically think about factors that were under your control that could have completely justified making you leave the program.

Being self-critical is hard, because one often finds things in oneself that one doesn't like. At the same time, it's what makes people better persons. I don't see any of this introspection in your post.

Comment: Do you really expect that, through introspection, the OP will find factors that will justify making her leave the program *through harassment*?  I cannot begin to imagine what such a factor would be.

Comment: There has been plenty of introspection on my part. Indeed, I blamed myself for a long time. Why else would I ask such a question of strangers if I was not sure myself? But, I am not apt to bleeding from the soul on public forums. I simply wanted to know if such a scenario could be read the same way that I, after 17 years, have come to read it.  Incidentally, I had no idea the conspiracy existed when I was a student. I found out after I moved on to graduate school from the perp/prof himself.  Funny how he was so confident I would do nothing. Indeed, I was terrified because he had tenure.

Comment: I did not leave the program. I stayed and completed the degree - my second of a double major.